# MySql Moving from development to production into a different user

Tags: mysqldump

I have a project that need to be moved to production (for the first time). The database includes few tens of tables and procedures/functions. They were all created under the ROOT user (yes, bad practice I know).

Now, I need to move the whole thing to production and obviously NOT under the MySQL ROOT user.

I thought to do the following, but would appreciate an expert opinion before I engage into it:

1. Get a backup using `mysqldump -u root -p -R MySB > dump.sql`,
2. Edit the file and replace all instances of root with correct_user (where correct_user would be the MySQL user owning all the tables and routines),
3. Create the same user within the production DB,
4. Restore from the dump file using `mysqldump -u correct_user -p -R MySB < dump.sql`.

Can anyone tell me if my plan is correct or if there is a better (and more formal) way to do it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the logic is right in your way. I will add a suggestion to make it more practical.

1. Get the backup **without routins**. `--skip-triggers`, and don't add -R is it is false by default
2. Make a backup of **routines only**: `--no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db -R`
3. Edit the backup file of the routine, and create the user in the new DB
4. Restore the data backup file
5. Restore the routines backup file.